# Expression tree to create lambda for generating a c# dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression-trees

I have a stream of thousands of data which I need to transform and add to a list. The transformation happens through the reflection similar to following

```
_myObservable.Subscribe(d => {
    PropertyInfo[] props = d.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    var propValDict = props.ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => prop.GetValue(d, null));
    myList.Add(propValDict);
});

// Datatype of d is determined during runtime and there are only 8 possibilities of the type
```

But this approach is slowing down the performance and I expect the use of reflection might be the reason. I am thinking of improving the performance by some other means.

Suggestions seem to point at use of Expression trees, create compiled lambda `(Func<object,Dictionary<string, object>>)` and store it in a lookup dictionary before hand.

```
//Foreach possibleType in PossibleTypes, Do below

PropertyInfo[] props = possibleType.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

var rootParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "d");
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(PropertyInfo), "prop");
var propertyFirst = Expression.Property(param, "Name");

var param2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(PropertyInfo), "prop");
var callMethod = Expression.Call(param2, typeof(PropertyInfo).GetMethod(nameof(PropertyInfo.GetValue), new Type[] { typeof(object) }), rootParam);

var pro = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Array), "props");

var toDict = Expression.Invoke(pro, propertyFirst, callMethod);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, Dictionary<string, object>>>(toDict, rootParam);
var compiled = lambda.Compile();
```

I am having trouble to invoke ToDictionary of Enumerable class
There is something which I am missing with this approach or Will this really improve performance.

Please help...

Comment: if you want to know if it can help perf, maybe generate the equivalent output in C# as a temporary thing (it doesn't need to be pretty) when iterating over the props, and see how it performs?

Comment: "Will this really improve performance." Almost certainly not.  You're doing a bunch of work at runtime to eventually end up with a delegate that's exactly like the one you generated at compile time in the first example.  It's just strictly worse.

Comment: @Servy Depends on how often they process instances of the same type. `GetType()` and `GetProperties()` are slow.

Comment: If I am right, at least I could avoid calling `PropertyInfo[] props = possibleType.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);` for every data since there will be just eight PropertyInfo[] possible. But even if I store the prop infos in dictionary, I will have to retreive the value based on the `d.GetType()`

Comment: @canton7 But they're just making an expression *that calls those methods*.  So that slowness is still there either way.

Comment: @Servy The slowness is in fetching the `PropertyInfo`. If they *cache* the `PropertyInfos`, they can avoid that cost. If they've got 200 objects of object 2 types, currently they'll call `GetProperties()` 200 times, but they could reduce that to 2 times quite easily. Using expressions takes that one step further, and makes that `.GetValue` call cheaper (as well as caching the `PropertyInfo` as a side-effect). Again, if they have 200 objects of 2 types, this means that they encur additional cost twice, but the other 198 calls are cheaper

Comment: Obviously they shouldn't write an expression which then calls `GetProperties()` -- I don't think anyone's suggesting that. I think they're just confused about what path they're taking

Comment: @canton7 The second solution doesn't cache anything.  It still runs it for each instance.  If you cache the results, it doesn't matter which solution you use, it being cached gets you your win either way.

Comment: @canton7 "Obviously they shouldn't write an expression which then calls GetProperties() -- I don't think anyone's suggesting that. " Their second solution, the one they're asking about, is writing an expression *that uses reflection to get the values*, rather than using reflection to construct an expression like you showed at the start of your answer, so yes, they *are* suggesting that, and I was explaining to them why that's not productive.

Comment: @canton7 second solution is where the property infos will be cached for all possible types, but even if its cached the retrieval will be still using d.GetType()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When thinking with expressions, you always need to figure out what the equivalent C# code would look like. In this case, the equivalent C# code wouldn't be looping over a collection of `PropertyInfo`, instead it would probably look like:

```
public static Func<object, Dictionary<string, object>> CreateConvertToPropertyDict<T>()
{
    return input =>
    {
        var d = (T)input;
        return new Dictionary<string, object>())
        {
            { "Foo", d.Foo },
            { "Bar", d.Bar },
        };
    };
}
myList.Add(propValDict);
```

Move sidewards in the land of expressions, and you end up with something like:

```
public static Func<object, Dictionary<string, object>> CreatePropertyDict(Type type)
{
    // Consider caching these in a static field, since they're constant
    var dictType = typeof(Dictionary<string, object>);
    var dictCtor = dictType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int) });
    var dictAddMethod = dictType.GetMethod("Add");

    var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    
    var blockExpressions = new List<Expression>();
    
    // 'object input' is our input parameter
    var inputParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "input");
    // MyType d;
    var dVariable = Expression.Variable(type, "d");
    // d = (MyType)inputObject;
    blockExpressions.Add(Expression.Assign(dVariable, Expression.Convert(inputParameter, type)));
    // Dictionary<string, object> dict;
    var dictVariable = Expression.Variable(dictType, "dict");
    // dict = new Dictionary<string, object>(3) (or however many properties there are)
    blockExpressions.Add(Expression.Assign(dictVariable, Expression.New(dictCtor, Expression.Constant(properties.Length))));
    
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var propertyAccess = Expression.Property(dVariable, property);
        // dict.Add("Foo", (object)d.Foo)
        blockExpressions.Add(Expression.Call(
            dictVariable,
            dictAddMethod,
            Expression.Constant(property.Name),
            Expression.Convert(propertyAccess, typeof(object))));
    };
    
    // The final statement in a block is the return value
    blockExpressions.Add(dictVariable);
    
    var block = Expression.Block(new[] { dVariable, dictVariable }, blockExpressions);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, Dictionary<string, object>>>(block, inputParameter).Compile();
}
```

With the simple test case:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var test = new Test() { Foo = "woop", Bar = 3 };
    var expr = CreatePropertyDict(typeof(Test));
    expr(test).Dump();
}
```

[See it on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YrGOpT).

There are several more advanced usages of Expression here, and I'm not going to go into the detail of each one. Look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=net-5.0), and have a play around with the sorts of expressions that the C# compiler generates for different bits of C# code.

Comment: Will try this and see the performance. Thanks!

Comment: @Azeeb Make sure that you cache the *compiled* expression for each `Type` of object -- these expressions are expensive to create and expensive to compile, so you'll only see benefit if you do the right caching